# Redirect output in different directories in a loop

Tags: shell, text-processing

i have a file (list.url) with the name of the files to download inside different folders. The structure is like this:

> Content list.url:
>   list.url content in folderA:
>   https://www.encodeproject.org/files/ENCFF002CEL/@@download/ENCFF002CEL.bed.gz
>   https://www.encodeproject.org/files/ENCFF002DBD/@@download/ENCFF002DBD.bed.gz
>   https://www.encodeproject.org/files/ENCFF002DDJ/@@download/ENCFF002DDJ.bed.gz
>   https://www.encodeproject.org/files/ENCFF738TKN/@@download/ENCFF738TKN.bed.gz
>
> list.url in folderB:
>   https://www.encodeproject.org/files/ENCFF558JBX/@@download/ENCFF558JBX.bed.gz
>   https://www.encodeproject.org/files/ENCFF004WYV/@@download/ENCFF004WYV.bed.gz

`Input`

> folderA/list.url
>   folderB/list.url

`Output`

> folderA/
>   https://www.encodeproject.org/files/ENCFF002CEL/@@download/ENCFF002CEL.bed.gz  https://www.encodeproject.org/files/ENCFF002DBD/@@download/ENCFF002DBD.bed.gz   https://www.encodeproject.org/files/ENCFF002DDJ/@@download/ENCFF002DDJ.bed.gz   https://www.encodeproject.org/files/ENCFF738TKN/@@download/ENCFF738TKN.bed.gz
>   folderB/ 
>   https://www.encodeproject.org/files/ENCFF558JBX/@@download/ENCFF558JBX.bed.gz
>   https://www.encodeproject.org/files/ENCFF004WYV/@@download/ENCFF004WYV.bed.gz

I was trying a nested loop something like this:

```
a="folderA folderB"

    for i in $a;
    do
        for j in list.url;
        do 
           wget -i $i/$j;  
        done;   
    done
```

But the problem is that the files are not downloaded in the same directory from where the list.url was taken as input. Any idea?

Comment: can you post your `list.url` contents?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you must change dir.

replace

```
    for j in list.url;
    do 
       wget -i $i/$j;  
    done;
```

by

```
    for j in list.url;
    do 
       (cd $i ; wget -i $j )
    done;
```

this will download file in each folder.

- parenthethis are needed to create a subshell.
- I assume you have more than one (list.url) file.

Comment: I was not putting the parenthesis indeed, and it was not working then.. Now it works.